# sha256/salt password key storage

Tags: php, mysql, salt, sha256, password-hash

I have created a registration form processed as follows:

```
function register_user() {
   global $conn;
   $name      = sanitize($_POST['name']);
   $email     = sanitize($_POST['email']);
   $password = sanitize($_POST['password']);
   $salt      = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));

   $saltedPW = $password . $salt;
   $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

   mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, salt) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$hashedPW', '$salt')");
```

The login form is then processed as follows:

```
    function login($email, $password) {
    global $conn;
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($email);
    $query   = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT salt FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
    $row1    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    $salt    = $row1['salt'];

    $saltedPW = $password . $salt;
    $hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedPW'");
    $row     = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

    return ($row[0] == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
```

The user table is structured as follows:
user_id; name; email; password; salt (additional columns for password recovering, admin rights, etc.). Having submitted the details to my company's IT compliance department, someone with PHP experience (exceeding mine no doubt) has stated that I can't store the key for the encryption in the system - if someone got the file they could decrypt the password. My question is - is this correct? Is my process flawed? All of the research I have carried out indicates that an SHA256 hash with random salt is one of the best ways to go.

Comment: why not just use `password_hash()` or the compatibility pack and let the function deal with the salt. Not to mention prepared statements.

Comment: Don't store salt in separate column. Store it within the password and have delimiter where you can split salt from the password. Also look in to pepper too, it is basically a hard coded string/int combination which makes it harder to crack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't store the key for the encryption in the system

You haven't. You're hashing, you're not encrypting. salt !== key

> if someone got the file they could decrypt the password

No. Nothing is encrypted, so there's nothing to decrypt. They'd get only the resulting hash, which they'd still have to brute force.

> Is my process flawed?

Yes, but not because of their comments. It's flawed because you should never use SHA or MD5 or similar for passwords. They're designed to be fast, which is not what you want. You want something that intentionally takes a hunk of CPU, as to make brute force attacks untimely. This is exactly what the [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function is for. Use it.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use sha256,md5 etc for password hashing. I think you should use BCrypt for password hashing. This is the most powerful password hashing algorithm at present. `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` are used to hash and verify password for BCrypt. PHP 5.5.0 or greater uses BCrypt as default algorithm for `password_hash()`. Do not use your own salt. Let `password_hash()` do it for you.

Comment: Storing your salt in an environment variable means that you've got only one for all users, which is *far* less secure than having a separate one for each user and storing it in the database.

Comment: "He will be able to get all password within few minutes." No, he will get access to the hashes, not the passwords. They'll still have to be individually brute forced. But that's irrelevant, because if he has access to the database then salt is the least of your worries, as he can just write his own new hash. "i do not recommend to use salt in BCrypt and sha256 either." No. Always use salt. The nice thing about password_hash() is that it does it automatically for you.